# Can a player in the wall get injured?

Tags: fifa-13

I know that a player can get injured when he trips over or when tackled.

But, can a player in the wall get injured if the ball is struck very hard at him?

Comment: I don't think that they'd spend time coding that.

Comment: @ardaozkal I'll take no as the answer then.  Thank you :)   If you can write an answer for the same, I would be happy to accept it!

Comment: @dawny33 I would wait until somebody posts something with evidence, it sounds like he didn't understand what you meant by "the wall".

Comment: @Dawny33 this is not an answer. I just said that I don't **think** that they would add a feature like that, think being the keyword.